# How to save activities for user HTML/JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made favorite buttons and if user clicks on it, it will save specific favorited item to a different page with `LocalStorage`. Code works perfectly but now I want to save this activity for specific user. And I'm using "Login With Google" button. I can get users profile and name but now I want to save those favorited items. So basically I want to get rid of `LocaStorage`. Here my code where I'm saving favorited items with `LocalStorage`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6b64e3f7bc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="favorites.html">
        <p>A<i class="heart fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <p>B<i class="heart fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <p>C<i class="heart fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <p>D<i class="heart fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <p>E<i class="heart fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <button href="favorites.html">Go</button>
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function () {
      const swapToggle = ($heart, toggle) => {
        $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart-o", !toggle);
        $heart.toggleClass("fa-heart", toggle);
      };
      const $hearts = $(".heart");
      const toggleString = localStorage.getItem("togglesM");
      const toggles = toggleString ? JSON.parse(toggleString) : $hearts.map(function () {
        return $(this).hasClass('fa-heart')
      }).get();
      $hearts.each(function (i, elem) {
        swapToggle($(this), toggles[i])
        $(this).data("idx", i);
      })
      $('.heart').on('click', function () {
        const idx = +$(this).data("idx");
        toggles[idx] = !toggles[idx];
        swapToggle($(this), toggles[idx])
        localStorage.setItem("togglesM", JSON.stringify(toggles))
        var favs = $('.heart.fa-heart').map((i, f) => `<p>${f.parentElement.innerHTML}</p>`).get().join('\n')
        localStorage.setItem("paragraphValueMath", favs);
        console.clear();
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my second(favorites) page:

```
<div id="favorites">
    <!--FAVORITES HERE-->
</div>
<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem("paragraphValueMath") == null) {
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      para.innerHTML = 'Empty... <div class="far fa-frown-open"></div>';
      document.getElementById("favorites").appendChild(para);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("favorites").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("paragraphValueMath");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't want to use local storage? why?

Comment: Is this question relevant for my problem?

Comment: your question is not clear to me so I want try to understand

Comment: you want to get rid of localstorage but you don't say how. Login with Google AFAIK just adds authentication but you don't have a state on cloud for free (I might be wrong on this.. but that's the key of your problem). You still can't save any state bound to a given user identity if you don't have any backend and yet you can't get rid of local storage.

Comment: you should save this on your db, so that user's favorite can still be serve whatever computer he use. i might be wrong, but i cannot imagine full-proofing this without a db.